# See external images loaded in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have some externally referenced images in my CSS:

```
.something {
  background: url('www.example.com/image');
}
```

How can I see what images are being loaded like this in Chrome dev tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option I see is to:

1. open the **Network** panel of Devtools
2. select **Img**
3. sort by domain (if not present, add the *Domain* column by right-clicking on any column header)

   or, better, use the filter box to **exclude** localhost (or other): `-domain:localhost`

See capture:

[image]